# Standardizing neural network inputs with a linear layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, standardization

I'm contributing to a ML software project and noticed something weird in the code:

They perform standardization by introducing a linear layer right after the inputs. This linear layer has the same number of nodes as the inputs. I've never heard of such a practice... How does this standardize the inputs?

The only comment in the code regarding this says: `We disguise standardization in the first linear layer to keep it seamlessly in a sequential PyTorch object.`

But I do not understand how this is considered "standardization".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do standardization is to subtract some value (e.g. the sample mean $\hat \mu$) and divide by another value (e.g. the sample standard deviation $\hat \sigma$):

$$
z = \frac{x - \hat \mu}{\hat \sigma}.
$$

When $X$ is a matrix, we can compute the columns' means and standard deviations; each is a vector. Then we can center and scale each vector $x$ with these vectors:

$$\begin{align}
z &= \left(\hat \sigma I\right)^{-1}(x - \hat \mu) \\
&= \left(\hat \sigma I\right)^{-1}x - \left(\hat \sigma I\right)^{-1} \hat\mu  \\
&= Ax + b
\end{align}$$

This should be recognizable as the same operations of a linear layer: matrix-vector multiplication and vector-vector addition.

In other words, if you assign $A,b$ the exact values that you want to use and then never update those values, the linear layer will do standardization for you. This is the stated design goal: put the manipulations for standardization into the PyTorch object, instead of standardizing the data prior to handing it off to the model.

Comment: But the exact standardization transformation is not assured, so why would it be advantageous to do it this way instead of standardizing explicitly?

Comment: It's absolutely assured if you assign the exact values you wish to use and then never update them. If you do that, then the standardization is explicit. As for why it's advantageous, this method is consistent with the design goal stated in the question: "We disguise standardization in the first linear layer to keep it seamlessly in a sequential PyTorch object."